# Kendo ui grid with dropdownlists

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have a kendo ui grid with dropdownlists in the cells. The problems is that I lose the selected row when somebody select a new value in a dropdownlist. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Not enough information to help you. Please post your view model and grid configuration.

Answer (score 0):

What is probably happening is that the selection of an item in the DropDownList is changing the value on the bound data item. This causes the DataSource to fire a "change" event so hat the table knows it needs to update. The way the Kendo Grid is written, when it gets a change event from the DataSource, it recreates the table cells. I'm pretty sure the existing table cells get removed from the DOM and a new set added in its place. When this happens, the selection is getting removed.

---

One way to preserve the selected row would be to add a function handler to the grid's "change" event, and save the uid of the selected data item. Then on the "dataBound" event, you can re-select that row.
For example:

```
var selectedUid;

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    ...

    change: function () {
        selectedUid = this.select().data("uid");
    }

    dataBound: function () {
        if(selectedUid) {
            this.select($(this.element).find('tr[data-uid="' + selectedUid + '"]'));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you help me to put a callback? Is there possible to do something like that in Kendo?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The function above is set as a callback to the `dataBound` event for the grid when it is passed in the options.